# Unable to exclude duplicate libraries in Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to connect library to my project in Gradle:

```
compile 'com.balancedpayments:balancedpayments:1.4'
```

When I click "Sync Now" project building without errors, but when I run my project IDE shows errors:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE :app:preDexDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:dexDebug UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;  at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596) 
>   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554) 
>   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535) 
>   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)  at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command: 
>   >     C:\Users\zen_75\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat
>   >     --dex --no-optimize --output C:\skip\TestPayment\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
>   >     --input-list=C:\skip\TestPayment\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   >     Error Code:  2 Output:    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: 
>   >     com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   >     Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;   at
>   >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>   >     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>   >     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>   >     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)   at
>   >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)   at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>   >     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)   at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)   at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)   at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

I found the description of the problem - it is a conflict of libraries. To solve this problem are advised to eliminate conflicting library. To do this, I do so:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'httpclient'
    all*.exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

Warnings disappear, but the error remains. Can you please tell how to eliminate these libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define "

This vexing error is caused when two or more copies of a .class file or jarfile's contents have been inadvertently included into a project. (Newbies to Gradle and/or Android Studio get blocked by this one often enough).

1. Try excluding it in your app's top-level build.gradle-

   ```
   android {
       ...
       packagingOptions {
           exclude('org/apache/commons/codec/*')
       }
   }
   ```
2. Check if the library was included as dependency more than once: review all of your project's build.gradle files to ensure it's been included only once.

   ```
    compile 'org.apache.commons.code' ...
   ```
3. A library or subproject may also includes a copy of the duplicated library or classfile: you can exclude it where the library is compiled into your app, look for its compile spec in your build.gradle file(s)-

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
           exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
       }
   }
   ```
4. If that doesn't work, try appending ", module: 'library'" to the exclude line, i.e.-

   ```
       compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
           exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'library'
       }
   ```
5. To determine exactly which library or subproject is including the duplicated classfiles, try running gradle with --debug and reviewing the console output in order to trace where that inclusion originated-

   ```
   % gradle --debug release 2>&1 | less
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I use `HttpClient` in api 23. I import `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` the problem appear. I use `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` solve it.